# Ansible - Moving ssh keys between two nodes

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keygen

Here is the problem I'm working on.

I have an ansible server
I have another server M
I have other servers B1, B2, B3... all known by ansible

I have a hosts file such as this

```
[CTRL]
M

[SLAVES]
B1
B2
B3
```

I want to generate a ssh key on my master (not ansible itself) and deploy it on my other slave servers to permit the master to connect on the slaves by keys.

Here is what I tried :

```
- hosts: CTRL
  remote_user: root
  vars_prompt:
   - name: ssh_password
     prompt : Please enter password for ssh key copy on remote nodes
     private: yes
  tasks:
   - yum: name=sshpass state=present
     sudo: yes
   - name: generate ssh key on the controller
     shell : ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N /dev/null
   - name: copy ssh key to the other nodes
     shell : sshpass -p '{{ ssh_password }}' ssh-copy-id root@'{{ item }}'
     with_items: groups['SLAVES']
     delegate_to: "{{ groups['CTRL'][0] }}"
```

The key generation works but no matter how I work I have a problem copying the key to the slave hosts

```
failed: [M -> M] => (item=B1) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sshpass -p 'mypassword' ssh-copy-id root@'B1'", "delta": "0:00:00.101102", "end": "2016-07-18 11:08:56.985623", "item": "B1", "rc": 6, "start": "2016-07-18 11:08:56.884521", "warnings": []}
failed: [M -> M] => (item=B2) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sshpass -p 'mypassword' ssh-copy-id root@'B2'", "delta": "0:00:00.101102", "end": "2016-07-18 11:08:56.985623", "item": "B1", "rc": 6, "start": "2016-07-18 11:08:56.884521", "warnings": []}
failed: [M -> M] => (item=B3) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sshpass -p 'mypassword' ssh-copy-id root@'B3'", "delta": "0:00:00.101102", "end": "2016-07-18 11:08:56.985623", "item": "B1", "rc": 6, "start": "2016-07-18 11:08:56.884521", "warnings": []}
```

Do you know how I could correct my code or maybe do you have a simplier way to do what I want to do ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more neat solution without file fetch:

```
---
- hosts: M
  tasks:
    - name: generate key pair
      shell: ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N /dev/null
      args:
        creates: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 

    - name: test public key
      shell: ssh-keygen -l -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
      changed_when: false

    - name: retrieve public key
      shell: cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
      register: master_public_key
      changed_when: false

- hosts: SLAVES
  tasks:
    - name: add master public key to slaves
      authorized_key:
        user: root
        key: "{{ hostvars['M'].master_public_key.stdout }}"
```

One of possible solutions (my first answer):

```
---
- hosts: M
  tasks:
    - name: generate key pair
      shell: ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N /dev/null

    - name: fetch public key
      fetch:
        src: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        dest: tmp/
        flat: yes

- hosts: SLAVES
  tasks:
    - name: add master public key to slaves
      authorized_key:
        user: root
        key: "{{ lookup('file', 'tmp/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Comment: Hello,

I was thinking of something like your answer with the fetch file but I wasn't a big fan of fetching the file before to deploy it again.

Your example to register the public key in the hostvars is more natural and lighter in my opinion. I'll test it today.

Thank you Konstantin